# SQL : how to store multiple values of subquery for calculation in main query

Tags: sql-server

My table is as following

```
item | date       | q_in | q_out |
----------------------------------
 a   | 25-08-2016 |  100 |  50
 b   | 26-09-2016 |  100 |   0 
----- upto 
 b   | 10-09-2016 |    0 | 100
```

I need  output like this :-

```
item | open_stock | inward | outward | balance|
-----|------------|--------|---------|--------|
 a   |    1500    |  10000 |  500    | 1100   |
 b   |     500    |   5000 | 1000    | 4500   |
```

where

- open_stock = balance of q_in - q_out upto 31-08-2016
- inward = total q_in from 01-09-2016 to 10-09-2016
- outward = total q_out from 01-09-2016 to 10-09-2016
- balance  =  open_stock + inward - outward

and my query is as follows which needs your help

```
select 
    item,
    (select 
         (SUM(q_in) - SUM(q_out))
     from 
         sale_table
     where 
         date >= '2016-08-25' and date <= '2016-08-31') as open_stock,
    SUM(q_in) as inward,
    SUM(q_out) as outward ,
    (***open_stock + inward - outward***) as balance
from 
    sale_table
where 
    date >= '2016-09-01' and date <= '2016-09-10'
group by 
    item
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't show any data, thereby making it hard to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: added a solution for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql:

```
select 
    item,
    (@open_stock := select 
         (SUM(q_in) - SUM(q_out))
     from 
        sale_table
     where 
         date >= '2016-08-25' and date <= '2016-08-31') as open_stock,
    SUM(q_in) as inward,
    SUM(q_out) as outward ,
    (@open_stock + SUM(q_in) - SUM(q_out)) as balance
from 
    sale_table
where 
    date >= '2016-09-01' and date <= '2016-09-10'
group by 
    item
```

Comment: dear @samar , thanks for your support but this query is not working .....

Comment: did you try the latest one on mysql? I just edited it. what error are you getting?